# How to grant bucket owner access to Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

When I try to execute the following code in an AWS Lambda function, it is executed successfully.

```
s3.getBucketAnalyticsConfiguration(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err)  {
  console.log(err, err.stack);
 }
 else {
   console.log(data);
 }
});
```

However, when I tried to get bucket versioning as follows, it failed. It did not print either err/data.

```
s3.getBucketVersioning(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err)  {
  console.log(err, err.stack);
 }
 else {
   console.log(data);
 }
});
```

I read the following in aws javascript sdk documentation:

```
To retrieve the versioning state of a bucket, you must be the bucket owner.
```

May I know how to grant bucket owner access to Lambda or its execution role please?

Note: The existing setup is as follows:

1. Lambdas can assume the Lambda execution role
2. Lambda execution role has full s3 access (s3:*)
3. Bucket has the bucket policy granting my lambda full access

Comment: I suspect it means that the Amazon S3 bucket must belong to the AWS Account associated with your IAM credentials. For example, I could run the Versioning command against a bucket in _my_ account, but it would not work if you ran the command (from your own AWS Account) against _my_ bucket. Does the bucket you are referencing belong to the same account as the credentials you are using?

Comment: Yes, the bucket belongs to the same account.

Comment: That does indeed seem strange. Can you temporarily create a new bucket and try it on that bucket? Also, FYI, if you have granted the Lambda function permission via an IAM Role (#2), then you do not need to also grant it access via a Bucket Policy (#3).

Comment: getBucketVersioning works if I execute the code through VS Code. It fails only when I test the Lambda through console.

Comment: Are both VS Code and the Lambda function using the same IAM credentials (eg the same IAM Role)?

Comment: I created the Lambda using a profile from credentials file and ran test from console. However, from VS Code, I ran the node command using the assumed temp. credentials of the same role.